# jquery: slideshow, when you're in another browser tab for a bit, then go back to the tab with the slideshow, it flips out

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, setinterval

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/B7Rhe/8/

In Chrome, when a browser tab is inactive, chrome slows any setInterval to only happen every second, even though my slideshow is once every two seconds, it's still messing up.

go to the page above and see how there's a slideshow there, now click on another tab in your browser window, stay there for 15 or so seconds, then click back to the tab with the slideshow, the slideshow will try to quickly fade in and out every slide to get caught up. But then I look at these simple slideshows and it doesn't happen to them:

http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Then on Jonathan Snook's small slideshow it messes up like mine, but a plugin was made of his script and the plugin example doesn't mess up...?

**1 (messes up) Jonathan Snook's script:**
http://snook.ca/technical/fade/fade.html

**2 (doesnt mess up)Plugin of the above:**
http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/slideshow

QUESTION: why does mine mess up, and Jonathan Snooks mess up, when the plugin version of his doesn't, and Jon Raasch's slideshow doesn't mess up either?

I found some other SO questions that deal somewhat with this but they didn't have the answer I need.  ere's the jquery, just for reference here at SO:

```
var x = 2;
console.log('Not broken');
$('.slideshow li:gt(0)').css({opacity:0});

setInterval(function() {
    var m = $('.slideshow li').size();
    x += 1;
    if (x > m) {
        x = 1;
    }
    $(".slideshow ul li:visible").animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if my answer is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating and testing your example links, working and non-working... I see the link that is working fine in Chrome, is actually using **jquery-1.3.2** . It looks like it's working fine in Chrome using the old Jquery framework.

See the update link : http://jsfiddle.net/B7Rhe/10/

Comment: Thanks guys, this has been bothering me for so long I can't tell you.  Thought I was going crazy. Good eye, Marc! And thanks for the question android.nick, saved me some answer-waiting time.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var m = $('.slideshow li').size();
  x += 1;
  if (x > m) {
    x = 1;
  }
  $(".slideshow ul li:visible").stop(true,true).animate({
     opacity: 0
  });

  $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").stop(true,true).animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
```

}, 2000);

inactive browser tabs buffer some of the setInterval or setTimeout functions. 
stop(true,true) - will stop all buffered events and execute immadietly only last animation.

The window.setTimeout() method now clamps to send no more than one timeout per second in inactive tabs. In addition, it now clamps nested timeouts to the smallest value allowed by the HTML5 specification: 4 ms (instead of the 10 ms it used to clamp to).